# Visiontek modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb-modem

Within a few days my broadband connection will be cut. Then the only way I can connect is to use a usb modem(Visiontek 82GH HSUPA). The problem is I cannot use the modem in an ordinary account and have to login using a root account to use it.

So is there some way to use an ordinary account to use the modem. Using `gksudo` or `sudo` doesn't help.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

For those who do'nt know how visiontek works,I will try to explain it the best I can. In windows Visiontek can be run by just inserting it and then installing a program. But in Linux its more complicated.

You have to copy a folder from the modem to the usr folder. And in that you should first run the install script and dialup script both with root rights, all while inserting the modem.

When I run the dialup script in an ordinary acount it says the usb modem is not ejected even when it is while in the root account it runs okay (You have to eject the modem before dialup for it to work. This will open the built-in memory card reader.)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for this.

1. plug the modem into any **Windows** device.(I used my friends.).
2. copy the `Linux_dialer` folder into a USB or some other place.
3. Copy the folder into the `usr` folder in Linux using `gksudo`.
4. Open terminal and run `sudo -i`.
5. Change directory to the `/usr/Linux_dialer`.
6. Run the command `install` or `dialup` after installing.(Sometimes you will have to type the full path.).

I tried this only in Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know how to do it in other versions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

plug in your modem in system.in top click on network symbol that looks as wifi.click edit connections and click new connection.you can see the network name as mobile broadband or else.search that.you can find the network name and you can set even network type as 3G or 2g in that.

Comment: it works but light does not blink.but working little low speed.